# Measure fan-out and dataflow

Tags: c#, asp.net, measurement, dataflow

Is there any tool that can measure the following 2 characteristics of C# Code (eventually also complete ASP.Net projects):

fan-out: Number of external calls from a class.

dataflow: the total number of outgoing and incoming data flow for the module

(see: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=891476 )

Comment: I believe that NDepend can: http://www.ndepend.com/

Comment: OK, so I might have to try to get it to run... it only works for compiled ASP.Net projects, and for reasons I explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349330/metabase-path-for-iisexpress), I can't compile it.

Comment: Ok, got NDepend working (there was a long meeting in between) but you can't really use it for ASP.Net because every web page is a single assembly and so there are a lot of false warnings... any other suggestions?